# How does depths of nodes change after left-rotation in a BST (Exercise question from Cormen)

Tags: algorithms, binary-search-trees

> Let a,b,c be arbitrary nodes in the subtrees $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, respectively, in the left tree of Figure 13.2 (that is given below). How do the depths of a,b,c change when a left rotation is performed on node x in the figure?
>
> [image: figure 13,2]

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnHDX.png) is a snapshot of the original question.

**My answer:**

Since in the left tree, left rotation is performed on node x and node y is above x, so subtree $\gamma$ will have not be affected by the rotation, and so depth of c remains the same.
Now, since subtree $\beta$ goes up by one level, so, depth of b decreases by 1 and since subtree $\alpha$ goes down by one level so depth of a increases by 1.

**But I checked the answer online and they say:**

The depth of c decreases by one, the depth of b stays the same, and the depth of a increases by 1.

The online answer is correct if I do right-rotation of the left tree at node y.

Am I misunderstanding something? Please review my answer and correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Please review your question: in the figure, the LEFT rotation is done on the tree on the RIGHT, not on the tree on the left.

Comment: @Nathaniel I reviewed the question. The question is on the left tree only.

Comment: Your issue appears to be an error in the book, check it [here](http://hscc.cs.nthu.edu.tw/~sheujp/lecture_note/11algorithm/errata3e.pdf). Interestingly, this might be an error that started even in the first edition, see page 10 of this [pdf](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs410/1999fa/Handouts/typos.pdf) and look at the correction for Exercise 14.2-4. Upon looking at the 4th edition, it was already corrected.

Comment: @Russel Thanks. Now I get it. Anyway, can you check my answer if the question were the wrong one only?

Comment: @Esha with your assumption, you are right with the changes in the depth of $a$ and $c$. As for $b$, it's not clear, since $b$'s depth will decrease only if it is in the right subtree of $ \beta$. Otherwise, its depth stays the same.